# Contract method returns a Promise instead of a value

Tags: web3js

I am trying to store a unit from my smart contract in a variable. My code currently looks like this:

```
var variable = this.contractInstance.methods.myMethod().call({from: account, gas: 5000000});
```

^myMethod returns a uint

But instead of saving the uint, I save a promise. How can I save the uint instead?

Comment: Search how to resolve a promise. This is a general issue (not specific to Ethereum).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callback function with .then()
Try:

```
var variable;
this.contractInstance.methods.myMethod()
    .call({
        from: account, 
        gas: 5000000
    }).then(function(val){
            variable = ret;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `await` JavaScript keyword:

```js
var variable = await this.contractInstance.methods.myMethod().call({from: account, gas: 5000000});
```

web3.js was changed to use Promises at some point of the past. Some of old tutorials might be outdated.